# Query not returning expected results(CAML)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to remove an attachment from a list of attachments using the CAML, however; when I do the query it always returns both of my files.  I only need to get the file of the current one using the passed in value as the parameter.

```
SP.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TempAttachments");

 // Query
            SP.CamlQuery query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml =
                 "<Query><Where><Or>"
                + "<BeginsWith>"
                // Job Note Matches
                + "<FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\"/>"
                + "<Value Type=\"Text\"/>" + ID + "_</Value>"
                + "</BeginsWith>"
                // OR Date Modified is older than one day.
                + "<Lt>"
                + "<FieldRef Name=\"Modified\"/>"
                + "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"/><Today OffsetDays=\"-1\" /></Value>"
                + "</Lt>"
                + "</Or>"
                + "</Where></Query>";
```

Could the Beginswith tag be the problem?

Comment: Were both of the files modified before yesterday?  If so, both ought to be returned given that query.

Comment: I even modified them before testing the method again, and it still pulls both files back.

Comment: Do both file names start with the text you're searching on?

Comment: yes. They both start with the characters "ta"

Comment: Then both should be returned.  What's the problem?  If they both match the filter then why wouldn't you expect to see both items?

Comment: Perhaps I worded it incorrectly.  File A's name is ta101 and FileB's name is ta102.  I'm manipulating one file one at a time so when I'm done with the first file, I find it and remove it from the temp list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your CAML query needs to be wrapped in a `View` element when seeting the `ViewXml`.
2. Your `Value` tags are both malformed; you're closing the element in the opening tag, meaning you have malformed XML.
3. Your query has an underscore at the end of the value you specify for the file name, but in the examples you [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918809/query-not-returning-expected-resultscaml?noredirect=1#comment49875773_30918809), your actual files don't have one, so that shouldn't be there.

So your query can now become:

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = string.Format(
@"<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Or>
        <BeginsWith>
          <FieldRef Name='FileRef'/>
          <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
        </BeginsWith>
        <Lt>
          <FieldRef Name='Modified'/>
          <Value Type='DateTime'>
            <Today OffsetDays='-1'/>
          </Value>
        </Lt>
      </Or>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
", ID);
```

Comment: This brings back 0 files from the temporary list

Comment: @DemetriusParham Then apparently none of your files meet the criteria.  Before you weren't applying any filters at all, because your query was malformed, now you're actually using them.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding.  The query reads like this
"Return the result whose ID is equal to or begins with the ID parameter value that has been modified no later than yesterday"?

Comment: @DemetriusParham No.  It returns all items that start with the `ID` value, and it also includes all items that haven't been modified today or yesterday.  So the only items that *aren't* returned by the query are those items modified in the past two days that don't start with the specified ID value.  That said, it *is* worth noting that you're only looking in the root folder.  If you want items not in the root folder, you'll need to specify the proper folder or make the query recurse through all folders.

Comment: CamlexNET nuget/extension MISSING THIS, it builds awesome caml but doesn't wrap it to "view". Thanks!

Comment: @MaxGrass Odds are it was written to write CAML for server side code, where it asks for the query XML separately from other items of the view.